# Create borderless DirectShow Window

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, directshow, borderless

I am referring to this simple video player using DirectShow example provided [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd389098(v=vs.85).aspx).

The code runs and builds however I need to make the video player window borderless.

I could not find a parameter to set in the [CoCreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615(v=vs.85).aspx) function or the [CoInitialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543(v=vs.85).aspx) function which I can set to make the window borderless.

Here is my complete code for reference:

```
#include <dshow.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "strmiids.lib")
void main(void)
{
    IGraphBuilder *pGraph = NULL;
    IMediaControl *pControl = NULL;
    IMediaEvent   *pEvent = NULL;

    // Initialize the COM library.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("ERROR - Could not initialize COM library");
        return;
    }

    // Create the filter graph manager and query for interfaces.
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IGraphBuilder, (void **)&pGraph);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("ERROR - Could not create the Filter Graph Manager.");
        return;
    }

    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&pControl);
    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaEvent, (void **)&pEvent);

    // Build the graph. IMPORTANT: Change this string to a file on your system.
    hr = pGraph->RenderFile(L"D:\\dfs.avi", NULL);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Run the graph.
        hr = pControl->Run();
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Wait for completion.
            long evCode;
            pEvent->WaitForCompletion(INFINITE, &evCode);

            // Note: Do not use INFINITE in a real application, because it
            // can block indefinitely.
        }
    }
    pControl->Release();
    pEvent->Release();
    pGraph->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

What additional piece of code do I need to add in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this code [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/318203-playing-avi--c/) which does the job!

```
#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "quartz.lib")

#include <string>
#include <dshow.h>


int PlayVideo(const std::string& pFile)
{
    IGraphBuilder* pGraph = NULL;
    IVideoWindow* pWin = NULL;
    IMediaControl* pControl = NULL;
    IMediaEvent* pEvent = NULL;

    // Initialize the COM library.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return 1;

    // Create the filter graph manager and query for interfaces.
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGraphBuilder, (void **)&pGraph);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return 1;

    // Get interfaces
    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&pControl);
    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaEvent, (void **)&pEvent);
    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IVideoWindow, (void **)&pWin);

    // Build the graph (convert unicode filename)
    size_t _size = mbstowcs(NULL,pFile.c_str(),2); // Add 2 for ZT
    wchar_t* _wfile = new wchar_t[_size + 2];
    _size = mbstowcs(_wfile, pFile.c_str(), pFile.length() + 1); // Add 1 for ZT
    hr = pGraph->RenderFile(_wfile, NULL);
    delete[] _wfile;

    // Uncomment next line for borderless window display
    pWin->put_WindowStyle(WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS);

    // For fullscreen play, get Windows screen parameters and replace
    pWin->SetWindowPosition(0, 0, 800, 600);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pControl->Run();
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            long evCode;
            pEvent->WaitForCompletion(INFINITE, &evCode);
        }
    }

    pControl->Release();
    pEvent->Release();
    pWin->Release();
    pGraph->Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    PlayVideo("D:\\dfs.avi"); // play any format Windows can handle, avi/mpg etc.
    return 0;
}
```